# TV Show Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

## **Thesis**

---

Portugal has a contest show similar to "Who wants to be a millionaire?" in which is given a question, and the contestants have to try to guess **which of the 4 answers is correct** (there's only one right answer).

Anyway, here's the trick: there's something called a **"Joker"** in which a player can choose between **2 different answers**, and the "Joker" will exclude one of them. However, it can **never** exclude the correct answer.

> The question now is: **"What's the probability of the player choosing
> the right answer, after using the "Joker"?**

## First hypothesis

---

Considering that there are **4 answers**, after using the "Joker," we are left with **3 possible** answers:

> $$4-1=3$$

Therefore, since there's only **one** correct answer, the probability of winning is:

> $$\frac{1}{3}\approx 0.33$$

## Second hypothesis

---

Having **4 answers** in total (before using the "Joker"), we can group them in **2 groups of 2 answers each.**

Suppose that the 4 answers are named: A; B; C; D.

We can rearrange them in 6 different combinations: AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD:

> $${}^{4}\textrm{C}_{2}=6$$

Notice that each answer appears **3 times in all of the 6 groups**, which implies that each of the **two groups previously selected** has a 50% of probability of containing the correct answer:

> $$\frac{1}{4}=0.25$$

Each group has **two** possible answers:

> $$2*\frac{1}{4}=0.50$$

With lack of genetality, consider the **group 1** made up of answers A; B; and the **group 2**, made up of answers C; D:

> $$\mathbf{G_{1}}=\left \{ A;B \right \}$$ $$\mathbf{G_{2}}=\left \{C;D \right \}$$

If now I select the "Joker" to be only applied to the **two answers that make up group 1** ($\mathbf{G_{1}}$), the probability of **group 2** ($\mathbf{G_{2}}$) containing the correct answer remains the same ($\frac{1}{2}=0.50$).

However, **group 1** ($\mathbf{G_{1}}$) will lose one of the possible answers, wihtout chaning it's probability of containing the correct answer, since:

> $$1-0.5=0.5$$
>
> - **1** is the total probability;
> - **0.5** is the probability of the correct answer be on **group 2**.

That leaves us with one answer in **group 1** that has **0.5=50%** of probability of being correct, and two others in **group 2** each with **0.25=25%** of being correct:

> $$\left\{\begin{matrix} \mathbf{G_{1}}=\frac{1}{2} & \\ 
>  \mathbf{G_{2}}=\frac{1}{2} &  \end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow
>  \left\{\begin{matrix} \mathbf{A; B}=\frac{1}{2} & \\   \mathbf{C;
>  D}=\frac{1}{2} &  \end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
>  \mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{2} & \\   \mathbf{C; D}=\frac{1}{2} & 
>  \end{matrix}\right.$$
> If **B**, was one of the wrong answers.

Which means that **A** has a **0.5** of probability of being correct instead of the previous **0.33**.

## Question

---

I know that one of these hypotheses has an error; I'm just unable to find where.

Also, I know that this question is similar to Monty Hall's problem since the "Joker" can't exclude the correct answers. However, because there are 4 answers, I'm not sure whether that would impact the probability.

Which logic is correct and **"what's the probability of the player choosing  the right answer, after using the "Joker"?**

Comment: Can you explain the rules more carefully? You say "there's something called a "Joker" in which a player can choose between 2 different answers, and the "Joker" will exclude one of them. However, it can never exclude the correct answer."  I don't really understand what this means. Does the player pick two answers? Or does somebody else pick them? If the player, what happens if the true answer isn't included? If somebody else, how are they chosen?

Comment: @Blitzer It's the player himself who chooses the 2 answers from the 4 available. The answers excluded is random, which means that, if the true answer isn't included each has the same probability of being eliminated (but only one answers will be eliminated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that the contestant has no idea which answer is correct, chooses two of the answers randomly, and always goes with the answer that the Joker did not eliminate.

In this case, the contestant wins if and only if the correct answer was one of the two chosen.  Therefore, there is a 50% chance of winning the prize.

Comment: I think this is probably what the OP has in mind, and I'm impressed that you were able to figure that out.

Comment: @saulspatz I was the keeper of the rec.puzzles FAQ in the late '90's. Interpreting Monty Hall variants is my superpower.  ^_^

Comment: @MatthewDaly It appears to be such a simple explanation, but I'm not sure if I completely understood it. What if the correct answer isn't one of the two chosen? And why can't we just see the problem as a whole, in which there's 3 answers and only one of them is correct? Maybe I didn't make it clear, but after using the Joker, the contestant is free to choose from any of the 3 left answers.

Comment: @DiogoSousa You are allowed to pick one of the answers that you didn't choose in the first phase, but it hurts your chance of winning. The strategy I outline gives you a 50% chance of winning.  If you decide to ignore the information you learned from using the Joker, your chance of winning with one of the other two answers is the same 25% it would have been if the Joker hadn't been used at all.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Yes, I do understand that. The only thing I don't understand is how the Joker can, in detail, increase the chance of winning from 25% to 50% by just eliminating one answer. Why shouldn't it increase from 25% to 33% instead? On the one hand, it makes sense (according to the second hypothesis), but it still sounds odd how eliminating an answer in a group of 2 can make the one left more probable of winning than the other two from the other group.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible event for player.

First event = Choosing two wrong answer in the beginning

Secend event = Choosing true and a wrong answer in the beginning

First event = Lets choose two random answer for our sample space such that $C(4,2)=6$ ways . Then choose $2$ wrong answer among $3$ wrong answers such that $C(3,2)=3$ ways. Thus , the probability of choosing two wrong answer is $\frac{3}{6}$.

Now, we should eliminate one of these two wrong answers , we can select that which one will be eliminated by $C(2,1)=2$ ways. At last, find the probability of chhosing true answer among $2$ wrong and one true answer which is $\frac{1}{3}$

Result= $\frac{3}{6} \times 2 \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{6}$.

Second event = Choosing the true and one false answer.

We can select $3$ different false answer along with true answer . Hence , our probability of selecting the true ans one false is $\frac{3}{6}$. After that , we should select the true answer from a sample space consisting of $2$ false and the true such that $\frac{1}{3}$

Thus our result is  $\frac{3}{6} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6} $

As a result , when we add those two events , we see that $\frac{2}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2} = 0.5$