# Probability of Choosing the Correct Answer After Eliminating Known Wrong Options

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello Math Stack Exchange Community,

I'm working on a probability problem and would like to get your insights on it. The problem is as follows:

In a multiple-choice test, there are 5 possible answers. A student, knows for certain that 2 of the options are incorrect and he always eliminates these wrong answers. What is the probability of the student selecting the correct answer from the remaining options?

My initial thought is that since the student can eliminate 2 wrong answers, he is left with 3 possible answers. If he chooses randomly from these, the probability of selecting the correct answer should be $ \frac{1}{3} $ or approximately 33.33%.

However, I came across a related problem [TV Show Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172866/tv-show-probability) which involves a TV show and the probability of choosing a car behind one of the three doors, even after one of the non-chosen doors is revealed to have a goat behind it. The solution involves some conditional probability and I'm wondering if a similar logic should be applied to this problem.

Is the simple calculation of $\frac{1}{3}$ accurate, or is there a more complex probability logic that needs to be considered, similar to the TV show problem?

Thank you in advance for your insights!

Comment: No need to confuse. If you *know* that $2$ are wrong, and you choose one of the remaining three, the probability of being correct is simply $1/3$

Comment: @trueblueanil Thank you! But the same happens in the mentioned problem. In which you have 4 options, you exclude one that you know is wrong and you're left with a probability of 50% of getting the right answer.

Comment: In your question, you are eliminating *known* false answers right at the start. With the TV show, you are first choosing *randomly*, and *then* the answer eliminated is wrong (if it exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{3}$ is correct. Let $a_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ denote the event that the $i$-th answer is correct. We are picking an answer at random, and each of the events is equally likely therefore $\mathbb{P}$($a_i$)=0.2, for all $i$. To answer your question, without loss of generality, lets assume that we are looking for the probability that the first answer is correct, given the fourth and fifth are incorrect. We can do this because the events can be modelled by a uniform distribution.
Knowing that two answers are incorrect, is equivalent to knowing it is one of the three remaining answers. Therefore
\begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(a_1 | \text{"Answers 4 and 5 are incorrect"})\iff\mathbb{P}(a_1 | \text{"Answer 1,2 or 3 is correct"})\iff\mathbb{P}(a_1 | a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3)\end{equation}
There is only one correct answer, therefore the events are mutually exclusive so $\mathbb{P}(a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3) = \mathbb{P}(a_1+a_2+a_3) = 0.6$, therefore
\begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(a_1 | a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3) =\frac{\mathbb{P}(a_1\cap (a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3))}{\mathbb{P}(a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(a_1)}{0.6}=\frac{0.2}{0.6}=\frac{1}{3}\square\end{equation}

It is important to consider why the solution to the Monty Hall problem can seem unintuitive the first time someone sees it. It works, because the host will always reveal a door without a prize. Had the host simply revealed what was behind one of the 2 remaining doors at random, and it was not a prize, your chances of winning if you stayed or switched would be 50-50.

The case you presented does not have a similar effect because you know two answers are wrong from the beginning. If Monty Hall revealed a door without a prize from the beginning, any rational player would have a 50-50 chance of getting it right.

Lets now MontyHall-ify your problem. Say you know nothing about the five answers and pick one at random. Your teacher, reveals two wrong answers to you from the remaining four and allows you to keep the answer you originally picked, or switch to one of the remaining two. You should always switch! The probability the answer you originally picked is correct is $\frac{1}{5}$, and the probability that each of the others is correct is $\frac{2}{5}$, so you double your chances of winning by arbitrarily switching to one of the other two. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The multiple choice test scenario is different than the Monty Hall problem you describe.

In the Monty Hall problem you don't know *which* doors have goats behind them even though you know there are two goats. Only Monty Hall does. He then offers you a chance to switch to the door you didn't initially select (which you still don't know if it has a goat there or not).

The analogous testing situation is this: Let's say you have a a multiple choice question with 5 options, none of which you can rule out as obviously wrong. You then attempt the problem and select an answer (which assumes you see your answer as a choice -- already more informative than simply guessing a door). The proctor then comes by and reveals one wrong choice from among the 4 options you didn't pick. You are then allowed to decide if you want to stick with your answer.

As you can see, this is a completely different setup than the testing situation you describe.

As @true blue anil pointed out, you are able to definitely rule out 2 options and then randomly pick among the remaining three so the probability of being correct is 1/3.

Comment: Hey! I was reviewing this question again and I only have one question: What happens if the student selects one answer at first and then eliminates the other two based on his knowdlege? Is it the same?

Comment: @DiogoSousa Yes